# Optimising array assignment in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

What I have is an image-building function that takes "rects" which are arrays of 8 elements, all in range 0-1. Then, they are converted from 0-1 to real coordinates using the target Width and Height with the simple get_coords function. Lastly, values are assigned in the image tensor.

The **problem** is that **paint_rect** is somehow one of the slowest functions in my system (a larger genetic algorithm function that calls it thousands of times), second only to my distance-based fitness checking.

How do I optimise paint_rect? It seems like a very minimal function and I don't see any obvious improvements to make.

```py
def get_coords(w, h, x0, y0, x1, y1):
    real_x0 = int(w * min(x0, x1))
    real_y0 = int(h * min(y0, y1))
    real_x1 = int(w * max(x0, x1))
    real_y1 = int(h * max(y0, y1))
    return real_x0, real_y0, real_x1, real_y1

def paint_rect(tensor, rect, w, h, opaque=True):
    [x0, y0, x1, y1, r, g, b, a, depth] = rect
    real_x0, real_y0, real_x1, real_y1 = get_coords(w, h, x0, y0, x1, y1)

    tensor[0, real_y0:real_y1, real_x0:real_x1] = r
    tensor[1, real_y0:real_y1, real_x0:real_x1] = g
    tensor[2, real_y0:real_y1, real_x0:real_x1] = b
    tensor[3, real_y0:real_y1, real_x0:real_x1] = 1
```

Comment: Assuming this is the first part of the function which is slow, then using a Python interpreter is clearly the problem. If so, you could try to use Cython or rewrite a significant part of your code in Numba. Assuming this is the second part (the assignment), then you could try to perform the assignment in parallel if the chunks are big, but I think the problem is likely an algorithmic problem and if so and we are lacking information to help you. If the chunks are small then the problem is either the interpreter again or the memory latency (only optimizable using a low-level language)

Comment: @JérômeRichard paint_rect is THE function that is slow, as well as a single call to norm+dist in another part of the program

Comment: You're calling `min(x0, x1)` and `max(x0, x1)`. Just do `if x0 > x1: x0, x1 = x1, x0` to save about half the time.

Comment: You need to vectorize whole thing, so that `paint_rect` works on many rects at the same time. If you do not know how to do this, make minimal **reproducible** example that includes such change, will be easier for us to help you vectorize it